# Online Database for PPG (Photoplethysmography) signals (both Infrared and Red light readings)

Tags: database, data

I am looking for an online Database for PPG (Photoplethysmography) signals for SPO2 (oximetry) analysis. I have tried several sources but they only have single datasets labelled "PLETH" and not individual IR (Infrared) and Red Signals. Please help me find such database or let me know any workaround for this.

Comment: It may be me, but I don't understand all these acronyms.

Comment: I edited to question

Comment: Thanks! I'll not pretend knowing the answer, but at least I know it's about measuring oxygen :) I retracted my close vote.